# What is the best way to go through one column in a multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Suppose I have the array $array where:

```
$array[0] = {'a','b','c'}
$array[1] = {'d','e','f'}
```

And I want to iterate over the first column of the nested array in order to get 'a','d' only. What is the most efficient way to do that other than having a loop that iterates on `$array[n][0]`?

Comment: Why exactly is `$array[n][0]` inefficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **PHP < 5.3** you can use `array_map` function like as

```
$array[0] = ['a','b','c'];
$array[1] = ['d','e','f'];

echo implode(',',array_map(function($v){ return $v[0];},$array));//a,d
```

As @Rizier123 commented you can simply use `array_shift` as callback function  like as

```
echo implode(',',array_map('array_shift',$array));//a,d
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/441358)

Comment: Why not just pass `array_shift()` as callback ? Then you can write: < 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
$array[0] = ['a','b','c'];
$array[1] = ['d','e','f'];

$new = array_column($array, 0);

foreach($new as $v) {
   echo $v . ' ';
}
```

**Output**

```
a  d
```

For lower versions of PHP -

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $a) {
    $new[] = $a[0];
}
```

Comment: Actually this won't work with php < v5.5. Are there other ways to achieve this?